# VBA Macro not running

Tags: vba, excel

I created the following macro in VBA but when I call it nothing happens. Any ideas why this might not work?

```
Sub RemoveWords(DeleteFromCol As Range, FindCol As Range)

  Dim words As New Collection
  Dim r As Range
  Dim word As Variant

  For Each r In FindCol
    words.Add (r.Value2)
  Next r

  For Each r In DeleteFromCol
    For Each word In words
      r.Value2 = Replace(r.Value2, word, "")
    Next word
  Next r

End Sub

Sub Remove()

RemoveWords Range("A1:A233"), Range("B1:B5")

End Sub
```

Comment: Try to put break point at 'For Each r In DeleteFromCol', and check how many words added to the words collection.

Comment: When I test, it work well for me. Can you tell more that how you run this.

Comment: your code works for me, do you have the text in Range("B1:B5") in on of the cells in Range("A1:A233") ? for instance, I have "Rado" in Cell B3, and "Shai Rado" in Cell A70, it changed "Shai Rado" to "Shai" in Cell A70

Comment: Are you passing the right worksheet range to the sub? instead of just `Range("A1:A233")` you can try `Sheet1.Range("A1:A233")` it will refer to sheet1 range.

Comment: I think the syntax is correct, but when I paste the code into module 1 in VBA and close out then run it via the Macros menu (clicking run), nothing happens. The cell ranges are populated as well with duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Macro does not work because perhaps you are not passing mandatory arguments:

```
(DeleteFromCol As Range, FindCol As Range)
```

Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Got it work now. It was due to having cells with multiple words in them. You have to split cells up to contain 1 word each and it runs fine.